# How do you refresh a SFDC Developer org?

Tags: salesforce

Okay, this should be painfully obvious, however I haven't been able to figure out how to refresh my developer edition salesforce.com org.

How does one do this?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by refresh ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no notion of "refreshing" a dev org. Only sandbox orgs can be refreshed from the respective production orgs they are linked to. If you have made changes that you cannot undo in your dev org, such as enabling and configuring territory management, or registering an undesirable namespace prefix, create a new dev org and reconfigure it to the point that you are trying to achieve in your current org.

Deploy whatever code/work you've done into a new dev org with the Eclipse Force.com IDE (deploy to server...)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, just assumed like there sandboxes you could refresh a developer org.